# How i can remove android.permission.CAMERA from cordova build?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions, phonegap

When I build a cordova project it's adding android.permission.CAMERAA automatically. But I didn't added any plugin for this.

In that case, I am getting the following error message while uploading apk in google play

> Your app has an apk with version code ... that requests the following
>   permission(s): android.permission.CAMERA. Apps using these permissions
>   in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

How I can skip adding android.permission.CAMERA?

Plugins I have used

> $ cordova plugin cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
>   cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
>   cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
>   cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
>   cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist" phonegap-plugin-push 1.6.3
>   "PushPlugin"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you haven't got the camera plugin installed by using this command:

```
cordova plugin ls
```

If it is installed by accident you can remove it with this command:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera
```

Even though you didn't install the plugin it may be a dependancy of another plugin you did install, so double check your app functions correctly if you do remove it.

Comment: See the plugins I have used
$ cordova plugin <br>
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification" \n
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.6.3 "PushPlugin" @L Balsdon

Answer (score 0):

You can open all the plugin's config/plugin.xml file and see which permissions are defined in them or you can just open the manifest file and manually remove the camera permission.